# how to encode and decode url query string in php

Tags: php, jquery

i am calling an an event handler in jquery for search. search value appends with url string in jquery and send it php. 
my original url

```
www.sit.com/index.php?search=a&b
```

i encode this search string with

```
var search = encodeURIComponent(search);
www.site.com/index.php?search=(encoded search)
```

but i don't know how to decode this search string to execute. Please help how to decode this string in php. Thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Are you sure it's not already decoded in $_GET ?

Comment: yes i am only getting value like this, $val = $_GET['search']

Comment: And what are you expecting / getting ?

Comment: jquery send a%26b to php. i expect again it a&b in php so my query run correctly

Comment: The browser will send `www.sit.com%2Findex.php%3Fsearch%3Da%26b` to the server. PHP will decode it to `"www.sit.com/index.php?search=a&b"` before putting it in `$_GET`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`urldecode(your_string)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @agconti "use urldecode(your_string) function" <<< this is the answer, link is only a additional information to source of the answer.

Comment: I'd also doubt the PHP documentation would become invalid